# Copying file on upload and paste it to www folder location

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to upload a file in Shiny and copy it to a WWW folder. My code is uploading file, but it is not copying file to WWW folder location. How can I do this? Am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Following file "ui.R" is also in www folder:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    fileInput("upload", "Upload", multiple = FALSE)
  )),

  server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){               
    observe({
      if (is.null(input$upload)) return()
      file.copy(input$upload$datapath, "\\C:\\Users\\'XXX XXX'\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.4\\shiny\\www\\")
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: What is a WWW folder?

Comment: @42- "C:\Users\'XXX XXX'\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\shiny\www". It is just a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it's a simple issue with the string mentioned in the output path. I was able to get the code below working without issues.

If I try to upload a file called *temp.R* using the app, then it is being renamed to *0.R* as the complete file name has not been specified in `file.copy`. Provide the complete file name if you want it to work irrespective of the name in the user's system, e.g `file.copy(input$upload$datapath, "C:\\NotBackedUp\\user_upload.R", overwrite = TRUE)`.

You can retrieve the original name using `input$upload$name`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    fileInput("upload", "Upload", multiple = FALSE)
  )),

  server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){               
    observe({
      if (is.null(input$upload)) return()
      file.copy(input$upload$datapath,
                "C:\\NotBackedUp", overwrite = TRUE)
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: I am using this file.copy(input$upload$datapath, "C://Users//'Tayyab Salman'//Documents//R//win-library//3.4//shiny//www//sample.R"). But it is not working for me.

Comment: If you are using UNIX style `/` then it should be a single one and not double. Also are you able to navigate to this folder in Windows Explorer? Do you have permission to create a file there?

Comment: @radmuzon , yes I have permission